# Embedding Google Calendar into Website - Multiple users on calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I believe I understand how to embed a single google calendar no problem. I simply goto settings > select my calendar > click customize > and then I can customize how I want it to look. **I know there are many examples of how to do this part. Please read further for how I am having problems with more users for the embedding tool part.**

I am trying to have one calendar combine two other gmail accounts. To make it simple, I will call my combining account, account A and the other two accounts I want it to pull from E and C. I have successfully added them to where I can view them together when just going to the default calendar view:

[image]

However when I goto the embedding tool, I don't see the second calendar (listed as C in the first image) as an option:

[image]

Notice how the "E" email address shows up but the "C" one does not.

So how do I get calendar "C" to show up on the embedding tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a direct way to have the "C" calendar show up on the joined account "A". The work around I did find is if I went into account "E", (which did display correctly on A) shared calendar "C" with "E" and **selected it** inside of calendar "E".

Once I had it selected actually then it started to show up on calendar A.